# web3 (then property) in ethereum node

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, rpc

Would you please help: When I run the below command in my nodejs console I get the below error: (I am using web3 0.20.0) on Windows 10

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(list => {accts = list})


TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
> TypeError: callback is not a function
at c:\Users\Salam Khanji\Ether\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\property.js:119:13
at c:\Users\Salam 
Khanji\Ether\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:89:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (c:\Users\Salam 
Khanji\Ether\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:119:7)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (c:\Users\Salam 
Khanji\Ether\node_modules\web3\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (c:\Users\Salam 
Khanji\Ether\node_modules\web3\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (c:\Users\Salam 
Khanji\Ether\node_modules\web3\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of web3 do you use ?

Note that getAccounts() has been implemented only in the betas of 1.0.0. If you're using the version up to 0.20.0 the method does not exists and web3.eth.accounts will only retrieve an plain array.

Comment: I have tried to install the web3 1.0.0-beta.18 but it have not been installed successfully in my windows 10. Any idea how this might work please?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
console.log(accounts); // ["0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1"]
```

You can use the Promise version only from 1.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is because you're using web3 version 0.20.0, which uses callbacks instead of Promises. The `web3.eth.getAccounts()` function expects a callback function as an argument in this.

Just use this code below

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(accounts);
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```